# If $a, b\in\mathbb Z$ and $b>0,$ then there exist unique $q, r\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $-\frac{b}{2}<r\leq\frac{b}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

a friend told me about the following problem, but I have no idea how to solve it:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, with $b>0.$ Prove that there exist unique $q$ and $r$ integers such that $$a=bq+r$$ and $-\frac{b}{2}<r\leq\frac{b}{2}. $

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Prove it for non-negative $a$ first. You can prove that by induction on $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Existence:**

- If $a\ge0$, $\,b>0$, you have $q,r$ such that $\,a=bq+r$, $0\le r<b$.

If $\,0\le r\le \dfrac b2$, fine. If $\,\dfrac b2<r<b$, you can write as well:
$$a=b(q+1)+r-b,\quad -\frac b2<r-b<0.$$

- If $a<0$, $\,b>0$, by the first case, write $-a=bq+r,\quad -\frac b2<r\le\frac b2$. There results:
  $$a=b(-q) -r,\quad -\frac b2\le -r<\frac b2.$$
  If $-r=-\dfrac b2$, rewrite as:
  $$a=b(-q-1)+\frac b2.$$

**Unicity:**

Suppose we have 
$$a=bq+r=bq'+r', \quad -\frac b2<r,r'\le\frac b2$$
This implies
$$b(q-q')=r'-r$$
Now $\,-\dfrac b2<r'\le \dfrac b2$ and$\,-\dfrac b2\le -r< \dfrac b2$ , so $\,-b<r'-r<b$. As it is also equal to $b(q-q')$, this implies $q-q'=0$, whence $r'-r=0$.

Comment: There's no reason to take $a\geq 0$ as a special case. We know by the division algorithm that $a=bq+r, 0\leq r<b$ whether $a$ is positive or negative, and the rest of the proof still works whether $a$ positive or negative.

Comment: Also, what "last two cases?" The assumption in the question was $b>0$. There are no more cases.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: the starting point depends on what's known to the O.P. I took the minimal point of view – euclidean division for natural numbers. As for the ‘last two cases’, I forgot the hypothesis on $b$. Thanks for pointing it. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde{r} = mod(a,q)$,  and $\tilde{q}=[a/b]$, the biggest integer not exceeding $a/b$. So we have:

$$
a=b\tilde{q}+\tilde{r}, \space 0\leq \tilde{r} <b
$$

If $\tilde{r}\leq\frac{b}{2}$, let $q=\tilde{q}, r=\tilde{r}$, we are done;

if $\tilde{r}>\frac{b}{2}$, let $q=\tilde{q}-1, r=\tilde{r}-b$, it is easy to verify that $r>-\frac{b}{2}$, and $a=bq+r$.